# Impact sprinkler-increasing spray distance as it sprays

Tags: sprinkler-system

Is there an adjustment on impact sprinkler that you can make where it increases the distance as it sprays going  from a short radius to long radius and then back to short radius to long radius and repeating this pattern?

Comment: If you could it would overwater the short throw.  It's a hard problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you tilt the mounting post, you can spray a roughly elliptical pattern. (The sprinkler head will be at one of the foci.)

If this doesn't meet your needs, you can place two or more sprinklers very close together, set to non-overlapping arcs and different radii.